# The usage of "such" here

Tags: pronouns, parts-of-speech

> The Astronomer Royal tells us that we must expect the not-yet-visible
> universe to extend beyond that by distances which—measured not in
> miles but in light-years—would be written “not with ten zeros, not
> even with a hundred, but with millions.” Our solar system is the
> merest speck in all this. **Such** is the relationship between a human
> lifetime and the astronomical distances involved that it is unlikely
> that humans will ever be able to penetrate even as far as the edge of
> their own solar system.

[Ultimate Questions, Bryan Magee]

What is the usage of "such" here?

Comment: [**such**, pronoun, 2 : someone or something stated, implied, or exemplified
*such was the result*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questioned sentence is:

> Such is the relationship between a human lifetime and the astronomical distances involved that it is unlikely that humans will ever be able to penetrate even as far as the edge of their own solar system.

This could be rewritten as something like:

> The distances involved are so large, compared to a human lifetime, that it is unlikely that humans will ever be able to penetrate even as far as the edge of their own solar system.

This use of "such" is one way of introducing a comparison. This can be used  in constructions similar to:

> - Such is X that Z
> - Such is the relationship between X and Y that Z.

Z here is some conclusion which the author derives from X, or from a comparison of X and Y.

"Such" here means "of a nature that". This is a raqterh literary construction, not likrely nto be used in casual speech. It can also be rather vague. When an author writes:

> Such is X that Z.

s/he is not spelling out what about the nature of X that Z ius implied.  It might well be better writing to explicitly give the steps of reasoning. For example, the original sentence could be spelled out by something like:

> Interstellar distances are some large, and would take some many years to traverse, that it is unlikely that humans will ever be able to penetrate even as far as the edge of their own solar system.

---

By the way, the key sentence is factually incorrect. Using already existing technology, it would be possible to travel beyond the "edge of the solar system" in considerably less than an average human lifetime. Of course that is not relevant to the distance to the edge of the physical universe, which the author is discussing just before that sentence.

Comment: Many thanks, I want to ask you another question. I don't understand the role of the word "involved". Without that word, how would the meaning changed?

Comment: @XVI When the author wrote "*The distances involved*" the meaning was the distances that the author was discussing, the distances involved in the issue or problem. The author could have written "*The distances between stars are so great...*" or used some other expression to identify the distances, and it would not have significantly changed the meaning. [...]

Comment: [...] Also, the author was distorting things a bit here. First s/he discusses the size of the entire physical universe, exclaiming over how very big it is. Then the author speaks of "the distances involved" in leaving a single solar system, as if they somehow partook of the hugeness of the entire universe. This a method to make it seem that the author's conclusions have more support than they actually do. In general the author is playing games with scales, making astronomical distances seem even vaster than they actually are.